# CSS Centering text in a div with other elements

Tags: css

I'm trying to center some text within a div with a text box floating to the right. Without the textbox, everything is looks fine. Though when it is added, the textbox offsets the centering of the title.

Is there anyway to keep the title centered despite there being another element? 
Here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/poppypoop/WqrXF/

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 30px; text-align: center; background-color: lightgray; padding-top: 5px;">
Title Here
<input type="text" style="float: right;" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of floating your input, position it as `absolute`. This will require that the container of it have a position also, so make that `relative`

http://jsfiddle.net/rr2WW/

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 30px; text-align: center; background-color: lightgray; padding-top: 5px; position: relative;">
    Title Here
    <input type="text" style="position: absolute; right: 0;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your text field a set `width` and a `margin-left` that is equal to the negative of its `width`:

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 30px; text-align: center; background-color: lightgray; padding-top: 5px;">
    Title Here
    <input type="text" style="float: right;  width: 120px; margin-left: -120px;" />
</div>
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WqrXF/1/).